# Sending Slack message onEdit trigger from Google Spreadsheet, if the edited columns value matches specific text like Send or Yes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, slack-api

I have the below App-script which I am using to send Slack messages via Google Spreadsheet on Edit Trigger. I am totally new to coding, but have a fair bit of understanding, so, I researched and came up with this code. This script is working and I am receiving the slack messages but the glitch is that I am not able to store row values in an array and pass them into Slack payload.

My requirement is if I edit a specific column let's say I choose or type 'Send' or 'Yes' from the drop-down, I want to pass on all or some of the column's value of that edited row into my Slack message.

I know there is something I am missing in the below code and as per my understanding, I don't need the i++ thing. But, I am not able to fix it. Also, if we can put in something that resets the edited cell value to 'No' or 'Refresh' once the message is sent to Slack. It's my humble request to you guys if you can help me with this code.

Just to make myself more clear - I want to know how to send row data of edited cell onedit to slack. i.e. how we can post row data on particular cell edit from the same row. I hope this clarifies.

```js
function sendApplicationDetails() {
  // select the range from the Summary sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,61).getValues();

  
  // loop over range and send communication if "Yes" option chosen
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    if (range[i][59] == "Yes") {
      
          // post message to slack
          sendToSlack(range[i]);
          break;

      }

    };
}
  

// function to send message to Slack
function sendToSlack(range) {

  var timestamp = new Date();

  var url = "Slack Webhook";
  
  var payload = {

    "text": "Hi " + range[31] +
      "\n Here are the details. Let us know if you have any questions! \n" +
      "\n Student Name: " + range[15] +
      "\n Nationality: " + range[16] +
      "\n Chosen Country: " + range[21] +
      "\n Preferred Course: " + range[22] +
      "\n Date: " + timestamp 
    };

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you could share a sample table with us please.

Comment: Here is the sample sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lcIw1Qk7J77n3X97HwpTmwv_M7wtJrdmYyl7aIFZmDY/edit?usp=sharing

Hope this helps. As of now, I have kept column BH to be edited to send messages to Slack. That column number I can change later on. I just want that if I select Yes in column BH, it should trigger a slack message with edited row data in different columns where we selected 'Yes' in column BH.

Comment: Thanks. Please could you change it to `Anyone with link`?

Comment: @Muhammet Yunus Tunca - Done. Thanks

Comment: What do you see in **Executions** tab when you run your function, is the status **Completed** or **Failed**?

Comment: Muhammet Yunus Tunca - Execution tab status is Completed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and delete the trigger you created manually please.

```js
function onEdit (e) {
  var sheetToWatch = 'Database';
  var colToWatch = 60;

  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == sheetToWatch 
      && e.range.getColumn() == colToWatch) {
    sendApplicationDetails()
  }


}
function sendApplicationDetails() {
  // select the range from the Summary sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,61);
  var values = range.getValues();

  
  // loop over range and send communication if "Yes" option chosen
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][59] == "Yes") {
      
      // post message to slack
      sendToSlack(values[i]);
      sheet.getRange(i+2,60).setValue('No')
    }
  }
}
  

// function to send message to Slack
function sendToSlack(range) {

  var timestamp = new Date();

  var url = "Slack Webhook";
  
  var payload = {

    "text": "Hi " + range[31] +
      "\n Here are the details. Let us know if you have any questions! \n" +
      "\n Student Name: " + range[15] +
      "\n Nationality: " + range[16] +
      "\n Chosen Country: " + range[21] +
      "\n Preferred Course: " + range[22] +
      "\n Date: " + timestamp 
    };

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH - Muhammet Yunus Tunca

This worked like a charm. Really appreciate your help brother. 

Thanks again to you and Eduardo Elias Hernandez for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, I replace the loop for with conditionals respect the column with the answer "Yes", then I change the argument range[i] for range (a bidimensional array), and finally I add code to change the cell with "Yes" to "No"

```js
function sendApplicationDetails() {

  // select the range from the Summary sheet

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Database");

  var column = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  
  if (column == 59){

    var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();

    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, column);

    if (cell.getValue() == "Yes"){

      var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, row, 61);

      // post message to slack

      sendToSlack(range.getValues());

      cell.setValue("No");

    }
  }    
}

// function to send message to Slack

function sendToSlack(range) {

  var timestamp = new Date();
    
  var url = "Slack Webhook";
  
  var payload = {

    "text": "Hi " + range[0][31] +
    "\n Here are the details. Let us know if you have any questions! \n" +
    "\n Student Name: " + range[0][15] +
    "\n Nationality: " + range[0][16] +
    "\n Chosen Country: " + range[0][21] +
    "\n Preferred Course: " + range[0][22] +
    "\n Date: " + timestamp 
  };

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

}
```

You can add `&& (cell == "Choose")` in this condition to accept Choose

```js
if (cell == "Yes"){

  var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, row, 61);
  // post message to slack
  sendToSlack(range);
  cell.setValue("No");
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Eduardo Elias Hernandez for taking out time to reply. But, not getting any message on Slack, neither the cell value is changing to 'No' from 'Yes'. I am editing column BH. 

The code you wrote is not giving any error and it's executing perfectly fine. 

Am I missing something? I have chose to run function "sendApplicationDetails()" onEdit trigger. Do I need to deploy this as Web APP? Also, do I need to replace "fila" with some column number? Not sure.

Comment: I already did the row to column correction, regarding the slack problem, do you mean the slack api? if so try to see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=630QGYcCwg0

Comment: Thanks, Eduardo for all your help. But unfortunately, the above code doesn't seem to be working. I am still trying to figure out what I am missing because the code written to send messages was working perfectly. I just wanted to understand how to store values in an Array and pass them into the Slack function.

Comment: Hi Eduardo Elias Hernandez, Just to make myself more clear - I want to know how to send row data of edited cell onedit to slack. i.e. how we can post row data on particular cell edit from the same row. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ok, it is more clear and I understand, I will to correct the answer